# Function defined in .bashrc not recognized

Tags: bash, function, shell

I'm trying to make the function below available from a bash session, so I added it to `.bashrc`:

```
function del () { mkdir -p ~/.trash; mv "$@" ~/.trash; }
```

This works fine in a shell script, but when I call the `.bashrc` version from the terminal, like:

```
$ del test.txt
```

I always get this:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `test.txt'

I am executing `source ~/.bashrc` every time I change the file, and I already tried different ways of writing the function, what's wrong with it? It works in a .sh file, so maybe a special syntax for .bashrc is required?

#### EDIT

Turns out that the session kept an old alias with the same name, even after sourcing `.bashrc` again. `type del` helped me detecting it. Running `unalias del` or starting a new session solved the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Not sure if this will provide any meaningful information, but what is the output of `declare -f del`?

Comment: what does the command `type del` output, after sourcing `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @chepner it outputs `del () 
{ 
    mkdir -p ~/.trash;
    mv "$1" ~/.trash
}
`

Comment: @Dario it is `del is aliased to `function _del(){ mkdir -p /home/lucas/.trash; mv $1 /home/lucas/.trash/; }; _del()'`

Comment: did you write 'export -f del' in your bashrc?

Comment: @Dario it seems that the terminal session kept this old alias even after sourcing .bashrc again. It works in a new bash session, thanks!

Comment: Aliases override functions, in the sense that they will be remembered even if you redefine a function with the same name. To be sure not to execute an alias, you can use `\command` instead of `command`

Comment: Good to know, but the alias wasn't even in the .bashrc anymore, so I thought when I sourced it again, it would disappear.

Comment: @TheMechanic Nope, whatever was in your environment remains unless explicitly overwritten or unset.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's ammended closing paragraph:

> Turns out that the session kept an old *alias* with the same name, even
>   after sourcing `.bashrc` again.  Type `del` helped me detecting it. Running
>   `unalias del` or starting a new session solved the problem.

(This answer exists only to keep this Q out of the *unanswered* category.)

Answer (score 0):

I also had such trouble, not being able to use in scripts functions I had defined in .bashrc
Turns out you have to export these functions with `-f` option!

```bash
# In my .bashrc
ccd () { test -d "$1" || mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"; }
export -f ccd
```